# Braintree Payment store_in_vault: false not working

Tags: python, django, braintree

I'm using Python and Braintree with the Drop-In. I try to not store a credit card in the vault, but the option seems to get ignored.

Here is my code:

```
        result = gateway.transaction.sale({
            "amount": order.total_amount,
            "payment_method_nonce": request.data.get('nonce', 'none'),
            "options": {
                "submit_for_settlement": True,
                "store_in_vault_on_success": False
            },
        })
```

Although the option is set to false after a successful payment (sandbox) and a page refresh the payment method is stored.

Comment: What authorization are you using to set up the Drop-In on your client? Drop-In has [auto-vaulting functionality](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/javascript/v3) if the authorization is a client token created with a customer id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you're looking for: https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/issues/470

In your Drop-In config on the client, you need the following config for not saving the credit card with a customer_id:

```
        card: {
          vault: {
            vaultCard: false
          },
        },
```